# OnClick() Jquery call function from external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am writing a jQuery file using onClick() to be an event for a button. But i want to load another js function from an external js file. How can i do that ? i have been trying but no result

This is my main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dashboard").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#content').html(dashboardTemplate);
        // I want another js external file will be loaded here

    });
});
```

This is my external js file: The element #btnAddGroup is inside dashboardTemplate which is just a html file

```
    $("#btnAddGroup").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
    });
```

Thank you

---

Edit : Based on your suggestion

external.js

```
function addGroup(){
    $("#btnAddGroup").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
    });
}
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dashboard").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#content').html(dashboardTemplate);
         $.getScript('external.js', function() {
            addGroup();
        });

    });
```

});

Its still not working. I am trying troubleshoot.
thanks again

Comment: What's wrong with https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: Do you have control over the external file?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I tried getScript but no luck. Can u take a look my code above ? i edit it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way

Say this is you `external.js` file

```
function () funcEx(){
     console.log("This is logging from external function");
    }
```

you can call functions of `external.js` file in `main.js` file this way.
say this is  your `main.js` file

```
$.getscript("path/to/jsFile",function(){
 funcEx();
});
```

Hope you can get an idea

Comment: Hi. I tried but no luck. Please see my code above

Comment: what do you expect ? I mean what is your requirement ? Otherwise this code should work fine. can you please post your full code and explain how you want things to be ?

Comment: The code above is everything that i have now. basically, i expect an alert('test') when i click btnAddGroup button which inside dashboardTemplate. the even to click btnAddGroup is stored in an external js.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add event listener to an element which is not yet existing since external file is being loaded before you have clicked to create your `btnAddGroup` element, so the event will never be attached and fired, however you can add onClick listener to document and check if you have clicked the right element, using jquery 1.7+ it will look like this:

```
$(window).on("click", "#btnAddGroup", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('test'); 
 });
```

Comment: I updated the code. But still not working

Comment: If you use code load external file as you was loading it before and use document listener or window listener, it should work fine, unless your `alert` function is blocked or template document is an iframe or is from different origin

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will take some more time to see why.

Comment: Instead of alert try to use `console.log` and check console